# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dynamicQueues/myqueue] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dynamicQueues]

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've created JMS sender in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 as below and configured JMS sender in axis2.xml file. I'm getting the below exception when I run the proxy service. Using Websphere MQ JMS queues.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="StockQuoteProxy"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/myquue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactory=ConnectionFactory"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dynamicQueues/myqueue] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dynamicQueues]

Comment: can you share the configs in axis2.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my scenario using the WSO2 MB, the correct endpoint it´s this:

```
           <address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
```

Your proxy config use:

```
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

So, no response is sent to the client.
You need to specify a WSDL in the proxy config with an operation that does not have a response message or return a status = 200 with:

```
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Able to solve it as stated & also message is getting pushed onto MQ. But I am not getting any response.